# Jekyll: Include Menu at different levels makes problems

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I include an overall menu with jekyll at different pages.

So this menu is for example included in index.html but also at deeper levels like `/portfolios/someportfolio.html`.

Now the issue is that the menu links do not work at deeper levels.
They include the submenu path like `.../<b>portfolios</b>/menuitem.html`.

What can I do to address this?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code. Precise your directory structure and the liquid code to generate your menu. It's easier to answer a question if instead of an obscure description, it takes the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correct, you have a problem with relative URLs. Just use [absolute URLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676525(v=vs.85).aspx) and you will be fine. Have your include link to this:

```
/menuitem.html
```

If you want to make it better you can add a base_url and/or even a site_url variable in front. Like this:

```
{{ site_url }}{{ base_url }}/menuitem.html
```

This will make it easier to move your site to a subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I then used also "jekyll serve" instead of just using "jekyll build --watch" and visited the site on localhost:4000 and there it was all fine.

Comment: The relative to root `{{ base_url }}/menuitem.html` is more portable.